# IE8 took longer time to display results for Smartclient app

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-8, smartclient

I am using IE8 browser for running my app which is built using SmartClient framework.

This particular issue which I am facing is performance related.

Steps :
1) I search a keyword
2) REST call returns results and they are displayed on browser
3) But on Firefox it takes less time to display results. And on IE8 it takes approx double time to display.
4) REST call took same time on both browsers, So I guess its related to IE8 browser

Any pointer on this one can be helpful.

Comment: Is anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 JavaScript is pretty slow, and doesn't implement some methods of later browsers, so if using libraries like jQuery they will have JavaScript implementations for methods that in modern browsers have much faster native implementations.

You'll just have to improve your apps performance or use a browser that's less outdated. Try to perform profiling and determine where the performance problems lie. You may be able to make a few minor changes to reach acceptable performance.